# HTML5 color pick change span color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, colors

I'm making a form where you can preview the result. I've made this:

HTML:

```
<input type="color" id="color" />
<span id="colorchange">Foo</span>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#color").click(function() {
         var color= $(this).attr('val'); // Not sure about this
         $("#colorchange").css("color","+color+");
    });
 });
```

Which didn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Edit:** jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xgm34/

New edit

Comment: add your code in jsfiddle ....

Comment: added to jsfiddle, see my edit

Comment: At this moment, the input type color only works on Chrome and Opera. I think you should consider to use a jquery plugin if you want a cross browser compatibility.

Comment: That's fine. I'm going to use it by myself anyway but thanks for the hint! Maybe someday, browsers like Internet Explorer will step forward :)

Comment: I updated the some new concept check it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the change event in jQuery:

```
$("#color").on('change', function() {
    $("#colorchange").css({"color":$(this).val()});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j27Bu/

Answer (score 0):

use this code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#color").change(function() {
        var color = $(this).val();
        $("#colorchange").css("color", color);
    });
});
```

see this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xgm34/10/

Answer (score 0):

using on keyup it will change the color while typing.

```
 $("#color").on('keyup',function() {
        $("#colorchange").css({"color":$(this).val()});

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tamilmani/j27Bu/1/

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to close some braces and parentheses

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#color").click(function() {
        $("#colorchange").css("color","+color+");
  });
});
```

By the way:

- <strike>The color type in input doesn't exist</strike>
- dont forget to close yout input element **/>**

Comment: `"The color type in input doesn't exist"` - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.color.html